# React amchart4 rendering only watermark logo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amcharts4

I am trying to create a pie chart, to display data. When I edit the file and save to see the result, the pie chart suddenly loads onscreen(displaying the data correctly). If I refresh the page though, I only have the logo on screen loaded, no pie. Can anyone point me to what I am doing wrong?

Component:

```
import React, { useLayoutEffect, useRef } from "react";
import * as am4core from "@amcharts/amcharts4/core";
import * as am4charts from "@amcharts/amcharts4/charts";

import am4themes_animated from "@amcharts/amcharts4/themes/animated";
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

const Pie = (props) => {
  const chart = useRef(null);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    let pie = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.PieChart3D);

    let pieData = [];
    props.data.map((item) => {
      let obj = {};
      obj = { name: item.prod_name, quantity: item.prod_quantity };
      pieData.push(obj);
    });
    // ...
    pie.data = pieData;
    let pieSeries = pie.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries3D());
    pieSeries.slices.template.strokeOpacity = 1;
    pie.radius = am4core.percent(70);
    
    pieSeries.dataFields.value = "quantity";
    pieSeries.dataFields.category = "name";
    pieSeries.hiddenState.properties.opacity = 1;
    pieSeries.hiddenState.properties.endAngle = -90;
    pieSeries.hiddenState.properties.startAngle = -90;
    pie.hiddenState.properties.radius = am4core.percent(60);
    pie.innerRadius = am4core.percent(40);
    chart.current = pie;
    return () => {
      pie.dispose();
    };
  }, []);
  return <div id="chartdiv" className="pie"></div>;
};

export default Pie;
```

Update:
Component Statistics:

```
import Pie from "./Charts/Pie";

const Statistics = () => {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3001/statistics")
      .then((res) => setData(res.data.data.orders));
  }, []);

  return (
    <section className="statistics">
      <Pie data={data} />
    </section>
  );
};

export default Statistics;
```

Also, the css for the className='pie' :

```
.pie {
  height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: can you share the code where you call this component, and how you pass the data in it

Comment: I created codesandbox with your code 
https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-fast-djuxm?file=/src/Pie.jsx
but looks fine

Comment: btw you can create pieData array like so: 
```const pieData = props.data.map((item) => {
      return { name: item.country, quantity: item.litres };
    });
```
if you use map then it returns the array itself. You can use .forEach() otherwise

Comment: @m5khan Could you please submit your comment as an answer, since you both gave the same idea of adding the props.data to the dependencies, which fixed the issue, but you were first in answering and reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So since you are using `useEffect` with empty dependency array, your component `Pie` will only run the pie chart creation code inside `useEffect` on component mount.

Now since you are fetching the data using axios asynchronously, the data will be passed to the `Pie` component after it is already mounted. So now data changes will not be reflected in Pie chart.

adding the `props.data` in the dependency array will run the `useEffect` whenever new data is passed to the Pie component. (i.e. on props update).

```
useEffect(() => {
  // your code for rendering pie chart
  return () => {
    pie.dispose();
  };
}, [props.data])
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-fast-djuxm?file=/src/Pie.jsx

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a conditional render to check if data is not an empty array:

```
return (
    <section className="statistics">
       {data.length > 0 && <Pie data={data} />}
    </section>
  );
```

[image: Edit nervous-cartwright-64u9k]

Or instead of a render condition you can add props.data to useLayoutEffect dependencies:

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    let pie = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.PieChart3D);

    let pieData = [];
    props.data.map((item) => {
      let obj = {};
      obj = { name: item.prod_name, quantity: item.prod_quantity };
      pieData.push(obj);
    });
    // ...
    pie.data = pieData;
    let pieSeries = pie.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries3D());
    pieSeries.slices.template.strokeOpacity = 1;
    pie.radius = am4core.percent(70);

    pieSeries.dataFields.value = "quantity";
    pieSeries.dataFields.category = "name";
    pieSeries.hiddenState.properties.opacity = 1;
    pieSeries.hiddenState.properties.endAngle = -90;
    pieSeries.hiddenState.properties.startAngle = -90;
    pie.hiddenState.properties.radius = am4core.percent(60);
    pie.innerRadius = am4core.percent(40);
    chart.current = pie;
    return () => {
      pie.dispose();
    };
  }, [props.data]);
```

[image: Edit elegant-minsky-tjbuj]